# Using wp_list_table how to trigger update function "inline"?

Tags: query, wp-list-table

Ok, i have used wp_list_table to read data from a custom db table and i like to be able to update the database table by clicking the correspondig cell. Defaults are 0 and when clicked the value is set to 1.

so by clicking the cell updateVisitor() will be triggered "inline"

my function which i isn't part of the Visitors extend WP_list_table class

```
function updateVisitor($id){
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE tbl_visitor SET visitorPayed =BINARY(visitorPayed=1) WHERE visitorID = %d", intval($id) );
    $result = $wpdb->query( $query );
}
```

Comment: ok i think i must go the jquery/ajax way but i need to refresh the page to get the updated value to show ???

Answer (score 0):

ok not the most handsome solution but it works

i transported the update function to update.php also wp-load.php

```
$(".col_visitor").click(function(){
         visitorID = $(this).attr('id');
         //alert('testing '+visitorID);
         $.ajax({ url: 'update.php',
             data: {action: visitorID},
             type: 'post',
             success: function(output) {
            //alert(output);
            window.location.reload(); //reload so we see the updated values
             }
    });
    });//#end click
```